# what is the use of hive server and metastore server?

Tags: hive, metastore

I am new to hive, and some question confusing me very much. 
first, after installation of hive, I just run hive, then I can create, select tables. where is the hive server, what is the use of it. 
second, what is the use of metastore server, I know we need the metastore to access the metadata about hive tables, does that mean if I start a metastore server I can request it in other app and get the information?

Answer (score 0):

Metastore server talks to the backend such as Derby/MySql to store and retrieve table metadata. If any Hive component wants to get/set metadata, it calls the MetaStore APIs. APIs are such getTable(tableName), createDatabase(dbName) etc. Basically metastore abstracts and provides backend (derby/mysql/postgres) independent API layer. Similar to HiveServer this can also run as a server. If there is no metastore server running, then the Driver will load the metastore in its process. If metastore is running as a separate server then the Driver object communicates with the metastore over network.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I am writing a application using webhcat. However, everytime I send a request for a table describe, it takes over 8s to respond, I have checked the log, it called the hcat.py and load a bunch of xmls, and create directories in hdfs, initialize objectStore. Is it because the metastore server was not running? I add a link below. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49953349/webhcat-server-takes-more-than-eight-seconds-to-reply-on-my-localhost